# Calculating HPD-interval from lme(nlme-package)

Tags: r, model, mixed, mcmc

I wondered if anyone know how to create a mcmc sampling and calculate the HPD interval for a linear mixed model made by `lme` from the `nlme` package. I am familiar with doing this with the `lme4` package, but I need the temporal autocorrelation-properties from `nlme`.

Comment: this is not very easy: I may take a shot at showing how to do it by hacking `lme` and using the `MCMCmetrop1R` function from `MCMCpack`, but otherwise I can't think of a simple way to do it.  If you don't get an answer here, you might also try r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org .

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response and thanks for the quick reply. But, at the time, it seems like the autocorrelation wasn't big enough to worry about in my case. But for curiosity's sake (and probably future cases) it would be nice to be able to calculate the HPD-interval also for nlme.